# One query to return multiple rows for multiple values with limit

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume you have database with `author` and `book` tables.

I want to get 10 most recent books for each author.

Normally it is N+1 SQL queries.

- 1 to get all authors: `SELECT * FROM author` -> N rows.
- N to get their most recent books: `SELECT * FROM book WHERE authorId=$1 ORDER BY releaseDate LIMIT=10`.

I want to have only 1 instead of N queries, to get 10 most recent books for list of authors. ( maybe it does not make sense in case of performance / but I do not know )

- Like this -> completely wrong, because it returns most recent books in table not per author  `SELECT * FROM book WHERE authorId = ANY($1) ORDER BY releaseDate DESC LIMIT 10`

Is there a way to make SQL query to return most recent books for list of authors? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at window functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by a.authorid order by releasedate desc) as rn
from author a join books b on a.authorid=b.authorid
)f where rn<=10
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to window functions using lateral join:

```sql
select a.authorid, b.*
from author a 
cross join lateral 
(
  select * from books 
  where books.authorid = a.authorid
  order by releasedate desc
  limit 10
) b;
```

Comment: I have verified that accepted solution and this solution works correctly and with similar performance. Thanks.